# What is the purpose of renaming this key in a redis sliding window rate limiter implementation?

Tags: javascript, redis, rate-limiting

I'm looking at the source for the `redis-rate-limiter` [library here](https://github.com/Tabcorp/redis-rate-limiter/blob/master/lib/rate-limiter.js#L11) on line 11.

Going through the `exec`, using "10/minute" rate/duration:

- Create temp key prefixed with `ratelimittemp:ID` to 0 and set to expire in 60 seconds
- Rename to `ratelimit:ID`
- Increment `ratelimit:ID`
- Get TTL

What's the point of a rename here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a way to refresh the rate limiter counter. It renames the temp key to real key if the real key does not exist, i.e. `renamenx`.

If the real key exists, increase the current counter, and see if we reach the rate limit of current time window. However, if the real key does not exist, it means the the previous time window, e.g. 1 minute, has been passed, and we need to start a new time window, i.e. a new counter. So we rename the temp key (with time window as expiration) to the real key, and increase on this new real key.